# Maximum possible ways of distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, binomial-distribution

I want to know how can we find the maximum possible ways of distributing 'K' colors marbles among 'N' people of a family in any hierarchy of our choice (hierarchy which can have maximum possible ways is taken) such that no child has same color marble with him as of his parent i.e. immediate ancestor.

The model of the family is as such that there should be a Head of the family who does not have any parent and then there are children, any member of family can have any no of children ranging from 0 to N-1, head can also have rest N-1 members as his children, or any other hierarchy could be made to have maximum no of ways.

P.S. we can assume we have infinite marbles of every color available with us and every person should get a marble.

example: for N=3 and K=3
we can have 12 possible ways such that
Hierarchy to maximize the number of possibilities is A is the parent of B, B is the parent of C. And in this hierarchy of family we can have 12 possible ways of distribution.

Comment: I think you'll need to specify your model of a family hierarchy. As the question is currently phrased, I'd say that a family consisting entirely of orphans would yield the maximum number of choices, as there are no constraints, but something tells me this is not what you had in mind.

Comment: Question edited and model explained that is any hierarchy could be followed with one member as a head of family.

Comment: If I follow your intention, we should first work out how many distinct hierarchies are possible with $N$ people (without regard to people as individuals being moved in different positions in the "same" hierarchy), then work out the possible ways $K$ distinct colors ("marbles") can be assigned to each distinct hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchy doesn't matter. There are $K(K-1)^{N-1}$ possibilities in any hierarchy, since the head of the family can have any of $K$ colours and each of the $N-1$ others can have any of $K-1$ colours.

Comment: +1 Your incisive answer has dissuaded me from voting to close the question.